# Improving the solubility of p-dibromobenzene in a reaction with water as solvent

Tags: organic-chemistry, solubility

I am trying to react p-dibromobenzene with Fenton's reagent (in an attempt to see if I can add alcohol groups to the ring and observe if there is any specificity in its addition), in this case using %30 H2O2 and FeSO4. The reaction will take place in water, since the oxidation of the Iron Sulfate and formation of hydroxyl ions/radicals is the major mechanism.

The main issue is that p-dibromobenzene is insoluble in water. (Clarification: p-dibromobenzene is solid at standard conditions.)

I have been adding acetonitrile to the solution and stirring hard in an attempt to improve the solubility of p-dibromobenzene, but had little luck in dissolving it. Literature tells me that it is very soluble in toluene, but this poses an obvious problem for the alcohol addition. (https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/1_4-Dibromobenzene). It seems like this would be the easiest way to get p-dibromobenzene into solution.

Perhaps I could double the amount of Iron sulfate and Peroxide, and hope that it reacts with both? It would still be reasonable to separate the dibromo compound from its solvent since the boiling points differ by about 100 degrees.

Any tips?

Comment: Would adding an emulsifier and/or using ultrasound to form micelles, greatly increasing surface in contact with aqueous solution, be useful? Both might react badly with H2O2, even at 30%, though... fizz, if not *bang*.

Comment: There is a lot of literature on Fentons hydroxylation of arenes, have you looked at some of those papers to see how it was done?

Comment: Hi Waylander, one paper I found mentions using a 0.05 M Sulfuric acid solution https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja00279a057. I already have been adding a few drops of 12M H2SO4 just so I have acidic conditions, but this might be worth trying. The main issue is that I am working with a homogenous (solid/liquid) mixture.